# Can the arduino move the mouse to an exact location on the screen?

Tags: arduino

I have been looking into the arduino controlling functions on the computer. I'm wondering if the arduino can move the mouse to an exact location on the screen. From an esplora example code, I found this and am wondering if it works. Thanks in advance!

What are the variables in the function?

Code:

Mouse.move(mouseX, mouseY, 0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseMove) the `move` function will move your mouse of `mouseX` on the X axis, `mouseY` on the Y axis. The third argument is used in order to move the wheel of the mouse.

Note that the movement is **relative**, so in order to move a mouse to a precise position you need to know first where your mouse is.